# Comet - stamp other than filemtime

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for some solution like the .net observer for php, and I came across [this](http://www.screenr.com/SNH) piece of code, it is displayed below. My application should wait until database change will take place - new records or change of existing records status, and then repopulate lists of records on client page. The question is - I am not using a txt file like in the code chunk below, therefore I probably can't use the `filemtime` for checking changes or new records in database. How do I it with database query result?

The code chunk that needs modification for my needs:

```
<script>

var timestamp = null;
function wait_for_message(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_data.php?time_stamp=" + time_stamp, 
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data){
            var json - eval('(' + data + ')');
            if(json['msg'] != "") {
            alert(json['msg'] );
        }
        time_stamp = ['time_stamp'];
        setTimeout('wait_for_message(), 1000);
    }});
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    wait_for_message();
});

</script>
```

And the php file

```
<?php

$filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/data.txt';

$last_modif = isset($_GET['time_stamp']) ? $_GET['time_stamp'] : 0;
$current_modif = filemtime($filename);

while ($current_modif <= $last_modif){
    usleep(1000);
    clearstartcache();
    $current_modif = filemtime($filename);
}

$response = array();
$response['msg'] = file_get_contents($filename);
$response['time_stamp'] = $current_modif;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using this code before discovering node.js

it was long time ago but  you can simply add a column to your table named time_stamp and and when your adding a row put time() in it (or whatever that indicates the time of insertion ) .

```
$last_modif = isset($_GET['time_stamp']) ? $_GET['time_stamp'] : 0;
$current_modif = $query("select `time_Stamp` from table order by time_stamp desc limit 1" );
```